# Using Google Apis Auth Client Library with SSIS

Tags: ssis, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an integration services project in which I use a script component as a source.  In the script I read data from a Google sheet and in order to do that I have to authenticate using oauth protocol.  I tried to make the necessary references using NuGet but receive errors and have been told that NuGet does not work with SSIS.  I have tried to manually make the references and the script builds but when I run the package I get this runtime error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices,
>   Version=1.9.3.19383, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Your doing this in a script task?

Comment: Yes.  In a data flow task I created a script component as a source.

Comment: Its tricky and its been a while since i have done it.  You need to make sure  SSIS can find the dlls for the client library either put them in GAC or the directory in Sql server which for the life of me i cant remember what it is right this minute.  probably the same one where the dts dlls are.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear this error by adding all dll's in the NuGet package into the GAC and then referencing from there.  I then faced a version dependency error which I overcame by adding a binding redirect in my machine.config.  Not the most elegant solution but I just needed to make it work and other methods I tried weren't meeting with success.